# Issue retrieving href/url data from XML using Scala XML

Tags: xml, scala, rss

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <author>
      <name>/u/Kobe_to_Boston</name>
      <uri>https://www.reddit.com/user/Kobe_to_Boston</uri>
   </author>
   <id>t3_94t5in</id>
   <link href="https://www.reddit.com/r/hiphopheads/comments/94q6ks/travis_scott_stop_trying_to_be_god_ft_kid_cudi/" />
   <updated>2018-08-05T16:38:29+00:00</updated>
   <title>The Weeknd - The Hills</title>
</entry>
```

Using the [Scala XML Library](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki/). I am trying to get various data from Reddit RSS feed.

For example, to get the information about the title of a Reddit post. The following code is:

```
val redditPostTitle = (XML.loadString(xmlContent) \ "entry" \ "title").head.text 
//assume xmlContent variable is the contains the XML above
```

The above works.

**Now, the problem is, I want to retrieve the data from "link href" tag. I have tried various combinations:**

```
val redditPostUrl = (XML.loadString(xmlContent) \ "entry" \ "link href").head.text
```

But I get an empty string returned. What I would like returned is:

```
"https://www.reddit.com/r/hiphopheads/comments/94q6ks/travis_scott_stop_trying_to_be_god_ft_kid_cudi/
```

**SOLVED: Solution is:**

```
(XML.loadString(hhhContent) \ "entry" \\ "link" \\ "@href").text
```

Comment: fixed the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```
object Example extends App {

  val feed=
    <entry>
      <author>
        <name>/u/Kobe_to_Boston</name>
        <uri>https://www.reddit.com/user/Kobe_to_Boston</uri>
      </author>
      <id>t3_94t5in</id>
      <link href="https://www.reddit.com/r/hiphopheads/comments/94q6ks/travis_scott_stop_trying_to_be_god_ft_kid_cudi/" />
      <updated>2018-08-05T16:38:29+00:00</updated>
      <title>The Weeknd - The Hills</title>
    </entry>

  println(feed \\ "link" \ "@href")

}
```

Comment: Okay so I got it to work by doing (feed \\ "link" \\ "@href") Using a single slash before the href returned an empty String, thanks.

Comment: And for futher knowledge, why does href have to be prepended with an "@"?

Comment: because it is an attribute